# How to fill a big cavity on a wooden door frame?

Tags: wood, woodworking, door-frame, hole-repair, wood-filler

Due to an impact against it, the door lock casing in the wood frame has been uprooted. I managed to fix it back the metal part and some wooden pieces, but there still is a quite huge cavity with un-regular wood pieces inside.

Is there any way to fix it in a semi permanent way? I.E. Fill the empty space so i can paint it back to white.

Rearrange / any paste / paint?

[full size Image link](https://ibb.co/C91QJyq)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would push some [backer rod](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BQWOC0) into the space so it fills most of the void but not all, leave some space to fill with wood filler or vinyl Spackle.

Once the filler is dry you can sand it all down and paint.

Comment: I'll have a try in this week and let you know. Do you think I'll need to keep the backer rod in its place using screws through it or would the push of the metal plate would do enough?

Answer (score 1):

Short of a total replacement I'd say this looks like a job for a multi/oscillating tool to extract the damaged portion of this area and replace with some new wood, combined with a lot of wood glue and wood filler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You're right that would be kind of a great solution but I think I'll try to manage with stuffings for now like putty and or fillers! I'll let you know how it will it be gone. Thanks.